# MS ACCESS SQL issue with combine LEFT JOINS and INNER JOINS

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access has been just killing me when It comes to writing my own SQL queries and I hate it's GUI query tool. I gave up trying to combine LEFT JOINS and INNER JOINS now I'm doing all inner join's and i'm still getting murdered. Can someone link to me to a comprehensible MS Access SQL guide and/ or tell me what I am doing wrong here. I've tried putting my code in parenthesis, bracketing my fields. I'm at my wits end.

```
SELECT answers.* 
FROM (((answers
INNER JOIN caseInfo 
    ON answers.[ABAWDNum] = caseinfo.[ABAWDNum])
INNER JOIN Questions)
     ON answers.[questionID] = questions.[questionID]) 
INNER JOIN responseCodes 
    ON answers.[responseIDCode] = responseCodes.[responsecode]
```

I'm not sure if my picture of the error is coming up but it says Sytnax error in FROM clause and it has the parenthesis right after the Questions table is mentioned
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH8rY.png)

EDIT: Database relationships:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbHHU.png)

Comment: When I take out the last two JOIN statements the first part runs fine


SELECT answers.*
FROM answers 
INNER JOIN caseInfo 
   ON answers.ABAWDNum = caseinfo.ABAWDNum

Comment: I'd kill off those parentheses and brackets and see what shakes out. That one parenthetical that ends after `INNER JOIN Questions` is a real oddball. Separating the JOIN from it's ON like that seems problematic. I do agree that combining LEFT OUTER JOIN and INNER JOIN in Access is a royal pain in the rear. Access is pretty awful really.

Comment: The SQL text editor in Access is pretty bad. The brackets shouldn't cause a problem, they just specify that he's referencing table and column names as opposed to keywords and functions. The parentheses however...

Comment: I only went to using parenthesis after reading an article about it online. I don't use them normally in my script. I'll try to link the article if I can find it again.

Comment: So, what's with the joins at all if you're not going to select anything from the joined tables--you're selecting all columns from table answers (answers.*). Strikes me as more of a where exists type sub query (maybe performance is going suffer w/sub queries?).

Comment: `"I gave up trying to combine LEFT JOINS and INNER JOINS now I'm doing all inner join's"` > Just note that `LEFT JOIN`s and `INNER JOIN`s do two very different things and have different purposes.

Comment: @unigeek I start off just asking everything from answers, but later on my intention was to ask for specific things from the questions tables and the responsecodes tables. the answers table has the question ID which doesn't tell me anything. the question table has the question prompt which tells me what the user was trying to answer. And the responsecode table has the response description which tells me more info on the answer.  *edited*

Comment: `INNER JOIN Questions)` -- this is always wrong. Closing parentheses belong after the `ON foo.x = bar.y` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access INNER JOIN can only work on two data sets at once, so if you want to join more than two tables, you have to nest the INNER JOINS using brackets, as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb208854(v=office.12)

From that page it says the syntax to do this is...

`SELECT fields FROM table1 INNER JOIN (table2 INNER JOIN [( ]table3 [INNER JOIN [( ]tablex [INNER JOIN …)] ON table3.field3compoprtablex.fieldx)] ON table2.field2compoprtable3.field3) ON table1.field1compoprtable2.field2;`

Comment: I think this is the answer I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @AbeMauricio: if John's solution worked, don't forget to "accept" the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will give you all fields from the table answers that meet your join conditions.

```
SELECT answers.* 
FROM answers
INNER JOIN caseInfo 
    ON answers.[ABAWDNum] = caseinfo.[ABAWDNum]
INNER JOIN Questions
     ON answers.[questionID] = questions.[questionID]
INNER JOIN responseCodes 
    ON answers.[responseIDCode] = responseCodes.[responsecode]
```

Comment: I agree your code should work but I'm still getting a syntax error (missing operator) and it goes from everything under answers.[ABAWDNum] until the last line .   Is there some settings in my database that could be throwing me off?

Comment: @AbeMauricio: sorry about that. I forget that Access has it's own (dumb-IMO) implementation of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just to humor Access I used the GUI/Design mode to build a query.

Here's the query I got that ran. From a table with 674 records, it only returned 6 answers, but that is a separate problem that I have to deal with. At least this thing runs.

But I have a feeling once I start asking for left joins I'm in trouble. <_< F* access.

```
SELECT answers.*
FROM (Questions 
INNER JOIN (CaseInfo 
INNER JOIN answers ON CaseInfo.ABAWDNum = answers.ABAWDNum)
    ON Questions.questionID = answers.questionID)
INNER JOIN responseCodes ON (Questions.questionID = responseCodes.questionCode) 
                         AND (answers.responseIDCode = responseCodes.responseCode);
```

**EDIT**:

I used the GUI/Designer again to try to make a query that was closer to what I needed, which is all of the answers in the answers table plus just a few things from the question table, caseinfo table, and responsecode tables , and this is what I got

```
SELECT 
    CaseInfo.ABAWDNum, CaseInfo.Admin, CaseInfo.Unit, 
    CaseInfo.[ASV-DRV  Completed By], CaseInfo.reviewerID, CaseInfo.[Recieved Date], 
    CaseInfo.[Date Reviewed], 
    Questions.Question, 
    answers.responseIDCode, responseCodes.responseDescription, answers.comments
FROM 
    CaseInfo 
RIGHT JOIN 
    ((Questions 
RIGHT JOIN 
    answers ON Questions.questionID = answers.questionID) 
LEFT JOIN 
    responseCodes ON answers.responseIDCode = responseCodes.responseCode)
     ON CaseInfo.ABAWDNum = answers.ABAWDNum;
```

This is really insane. I'm going to have to study this really hard. It looks like access is very particular on how it wants it's joins, but this seems to give me the correct results. 674 records returned.